# Flex: Disabling wrongLengthError from ZipCodeValidator

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

Is it possible to disable `wrongLengthError` from ZipCodeValidator? I just want to show `wrongCAFormatError` and `wrongUSFormatError`. 
If I doesn't specify `wrongLengthError` to `<mx:ZipCodeValidator` then it show default wrong length error message.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<mx:ZipCodeValidator
    id="zipCodeValidator"
    domain="{ZipCodeValidatorDomainType.US_OR_CANADA}"
    source="{input}" 
    property="text" 
    wrongLengthError="{zipCodeValidator.wrongUSFormatError + '\n' + zipCodeValidator.wrongCAFormatError}"
/>
```